# R Plot Color Combinations that Are Colorblind Accessible

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

How do I choose 4-8 colors in **base R** for plots that colorblind people will be able to see?

Below is the base R color pallet. Looking for a solution in **BASE R** without the use of packages.

Base R Color Palette Guide:
http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~tzheng/files/Rcolor.pdf

Color Palettes for Color Blindness: http://mkweb.bcgsc.ca/colorblind/

Specifically how do I manually create accessible colors in **BASE R**?

e.g. "vermilion", "bluish green", and "reddish purple" as described in the paper figure below.

[image]

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/index.html, specifically *"They are also designed to be perceived by readers with the most common form of color blindness (all color maps in this package) and color vision deficiency"*.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Okabe-Ito palette

The palette shown in the question is also known as the Okabe-Ito palette as suggested by [Okabe & Ito (2008)](https://jfly.uni-koeln.de/color/). Since version 4.0.0, base R provides a new `palette.colors()` where this palette is actually the default:

```
palette.colors(palette = "Okabe-Ito")
##         black        orange       skyblue   bluishgreen        yellow 
##     "#000000"     "#E69F00"     "#56B4E9"     "#009E73"     "#F0E442" 
##          blue    vermillion reddishpurple          gray 
##     "#0072B2"     "#D55E00"     "#CC79A7"     "#999999"
```

### Qualitative palettes in base R

Along with this palette, various other qualitative palettes are easily available in base R. Specifically, the new default palette (called `"R4"`) has also been designed to be rather robust under color vision deficiencies. See this blog post for further details:

- Zeileis, Murrell, Maechler, Sarkar (2019). ["A New palette() for R."](https://developer.R-project.org/Blog/public/2019/11/21/a-new-palette-for-r/)  *The R Blog*.

[image: overview of various palettes in the palette.colors function]

### Sequential and diverging palettes in base R

In addition to the qualitative palettes above, base R also has a new function `hcl.colors()` since version 3.6.0 that makes many sequential and diverging palettes available that are also robust under color vision deficiencies. It provides approximations (derived using the hue-chroma-luminance color model) to many palettes from ColorBrewer.org, viridis, CARTO colors, Crameri's scientific colors etc. The default is the popular viridis palette. The following blog post provides more details and the paper about the `colorspace` package explains more related/underlying work.

- Zeileis, Murrell (2019). ["HCL-Based Color Palettes in grDevices."](https://developer.R-project.org/Blog/public/2019/04/01/hcl-based-color-palettes-in-grdevices/) *The R Blog*.
- Zeileis, Fisher, Hornik, Ihaka, McWhite, Murrell, Stauffer, Wilke (2020). ["colorspace: A Toolbox for Manipulating and Assessing Colors and Palettes."](https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v096.i01) *Journal of Statistical Software*.

[image: overview of sequential palettes in the hcl.colors function]

[image: overview of diverging palettes in the hcl.colors function]

Comment: I will add these citations them to the question and give another working example using these defaults you provided.

Answer (score 27):

These are the hex codes for those colors in the image you posted

```r
colorBlindBlack8  <- c("#000000", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
                       "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")
pie(rep(1, 8), col = colorBlindBlack8)
```

[image]

```r
colorBlindGrey8   <- c("#999999", "#E69F00", "#56B4E9", "#009E73", 
                       "#F0E442", "#0072B2", "#D55E00", "#CC79A7")
scales::show_col(colorBlindGrey8)
```

[image]

For more than 8 colors, [`rcartocolor`](https://github.com/Nowosad/rcartocolor) has the `Safe` palette with 12 colors

```r
safe_colorblind_palette <- c("#88CCEE", "#CC6677", "#DDCC77", "#117733", "#332288", "#AA4499", 
                             "#44AA99", "#999933", "#882255", "#661100", "#6699CC", "#888888")
scales::show_col(safe_colorblind_palette)
```

[image]

If you need sequential or diverging colormaps, check these palettes out

```r
library(rcartocolor)
display_carto_all(colorblind_friendly = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-07-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

The color scales in the `viridis` package are all color blind accessible. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/viridis/vignettes/intro-to-viridis.html#the-color-scales

If you need to use colors by name like in the pdf you linked to, match colors from the `viridis` palettes to the named list of colors. For 4-8, this is pretty easy to do visually.

Answer (score 2):

You could generate the pallete with a package and generate the 'hard coded' code that recreates them with base R only. Here for example 4 colours from all colourbrewer palletes in a data frame:

```r
# install.packages('RColorBrewer')

palletes <-
structure(c("#A6611A", "#D01C8B", "#7B3294", "#E66101", "#CA0020", 
"#CA0020", "#D7191C", "#D7191C", "#D7191C", "#7FC97F", "#1B9E77", 
"#A6CEE3", "#FBB4AE", "#B3E2CD", "#E41A1C", "#66C2A5", "#8DD3C7", 
"#EFF3FF", "#EDF8FB", "#EDF8FB", "#F0F9E8", "#EDF8E9", "#F7F7F7", 
"#FEEDDE", "#FEF0D9", "#F1EEF6", "#F6EFF7", "#F1EEF6", "#F2F0F7", 
"#FEEBE2", "#FEE5D9", "#FFFFCC", "#FFFFCC", "#FFFFD4", "#FFFFB2", 
"#DFC27D", "#F1B6DA", "#C2A5CF", "#FDB863", "#F4A582", "#F4A582", 
"#FDAE61", "#FDAE61", "#FDAE61", "#BEAED4", "#D95F02", "#1F78B4", 
"#B3CDE3", "#FDCDAC", "#377EB8", "#FC8D62", "#FFFFB3", "#BDD7E7", 
"#B2E2E2", "#B3CDE3", "#BAE4BC", "#BAE4B3", "#CCCCCC", "#FDBE85", 
"#FDCC8A", "#BDC9E1", "#BDC9E1", "#D7B5D8", "#CBC9E2", "#FBB4B9", 
"#FCAE91", "#C2E699", "#A1DAB4", "#FED98E", "#FECC5C", "#80CDC1", 
"#B8E186", "#A6DBA0", "#B2ABD2", "#92C5DE", "#BABABA", "#ABD9E9", 
"#A6D96A", "#ABDDA4", "#FDC086", "#7570B3", "#B2DF8A", "#CCEBC5", 
"#CBD5E8", "#4DAF4A", "#8DA0CB", "#BEBADA", "#6BAED6", "#66C2A4", 
"#8C96C6", "#7BCCC4", "#74C476", "#969696", "#FD8D3C", "#FC8D59", 
"#74A9CF", "#67A9CF", "#DF65B0", "#9E9AC8", "#F768A1", "#FB6A4A", 
"#78C679", "#41B6C4", "#FE9929", "#FD8D3C", "#018571", "#4DAC26", 
"#008837", "#5E3C99", "#0571B0", "#404040", "#2C7BB6", "#1A9641", 
"#2B83BA", "#FFFF99", "#E7298A", "#33A02C", "#DECBE4", "#F4CAE4", 
"#984EA3", "#E78AC3", "#FB8072", "#2171B5", "#238B45", "#88419D", 
"#2B8CBE", "#238B45", "#525252", "#D94701", "#D7301F", "#0570B0", 
"#02818A", "#CE1256", "#6A51A3", "#AE017E", "#CB181D", "#238443", 
"#225EA8", "#CC4C02", "#E31A1C"), .Dim = c(35L, 4L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("BrBG", "PiYG", "PRGn", "PuOr", "RdBu", "RdGy", "RdYlBu", 
    "RdYlGn", "Spectral", "Accent", "Dark2", "Paired", "Pastel1", 
    "Pastel2", "Set1", "Set2", "Set3", "Blues", "BuGn", "BuPu", 
    "GnBu", "Greens", "Greys", "Oranges", "OrRd", "PuBu", "PuBuGn", 
    "PuRd", "Purples", "RdPu", "Reds", "YlGn", "YlGnBu", "YlOrBr", 
    "YlOrRd"), NULL))
```

Here's the code used to generate this:

```r
number_of_colors <- 4
pallete_names <- rownames(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal.info)
pallete_color_generator <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal

# make color hexcodes:
palletes<-lapply(pallete_names,
                 pallete_color_generator,
                 n = number_of_colors) 

# turn into matrix:
palletes<-do.call(rbind,palletes)

rownames(palletes)<-pallete_names

# dump hard-coded R code to create the object to the console:
dump('palletes','')
```

Answer (score 2):

To create a custom color palette in base as listed in the question figure:

```
customvermillion<-rgb(213/255,94/255,0/255)
custombluegreen<-rgb(0/255,158/255,115/255)
customblue<-rgb(0/255,114/255,178/255)
customskyblue<-rgb(86/255,180/255,233/255)
customreddishpurple<-rgb(204/255,121/255,167/255)
```

Then when referencing in

`plot()`

Instead of using parameter:

`plot(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$hp,col=c("orange","skyblue"))`

Use parameter:

`plot(mtcars$mpg,mtcars$hp,col=c(customorange,customskyblue))`
[image]