# Raster-like timeseries graph in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, time-series, raster

I'm trying to recreate a graph like the one here using `ggplot2`.

[image]

I can get pretty close if I mess around with the size and shape of points using coord_equal, but...

Example data and code

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame()
Years <- 1990:2020
for(i in 1:length(Years)) {
  Year <- Years[i]
  week <-1:52
  value <- sort(round(rnorm(52, 50, 30), 0))
  df.small <- data.frame(Year = Year, week = week, value = value)
  df <- bind_rows(df, df.small)
}


ggplot(df, aes(week, Year, color = value)) +
  geom_point(shape = 15, size = 2.7) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(10)) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

## The problem is,

with my real data I want to "stretch" the graph so I can see it more clearly (my timeseries is shorter) and when I don't use coord_equal, squares don't fill the graphing area:

```
ggplot(df, aes(week, Year, color = value)) +
  geom_point(shape = 15, size = 2.7) +
  scale_color_gradientn(colours = rainbow(10))
```

[image]

Comment: Side note: please scrap rainbow colour scales: https://www.nature.com/articles/519291d

Comment: You can find better colormaps than rainbow in this thread https://stackoverflow.com/q/37482977/786542

Comment: This is amazing. I use colorblind-friendly colors in all my publications... why would I do anything less on SO? Thanks for the reminder, Tung :)

Comment: that's great to hear. The world needs more thoughtful scientists like you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this as simple as using the `geom_raster` geom?

```
ggplot(df, aes(week, Year)) +
  geom_raster(aes(fill = value)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = rainbow(10)) +
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! I just didn't know you could use geom_raster without spatial info. This is a real "face-palm" moment, but I really appreciate the help!!