# R correlation plot using ggcorrplot2: "x-axis" labels get cropped

Tags: r, ggplot2, correlation, axis-labels, area

I am using `ggcorrplot2` ([github page](https://github.com/caijun/ggcorrplot2)) to generate my correlation plots, since I need to overlay significance levels as `***` on top.

This package relies on `ggplot2`, so I thought it would be easy to change different features like axis label font size, asterisk color, gradient colors, etc. But it is proving to be more complicated than I thought.

My current problem at hand is that the "x-axis" labels get cropped out of the plotting area... As you see below, this isn't actually the `x-axis`, but rather labels placed on top of the diagonal cells. Hence, it is quite difficult to change them.

Check out this MWE. I first did this:

```
data(mtcars)
#change "wt" to a very long name
names(mtcars)[6] <- "a very long name"

corrtest <- psych::corr.test(mtcars[,1:7], adjust="none")
all_matrix <- corrtest$r
all_pmat <- corrtest$p

###

P <- ggcorrplot2::ggcorrplot(all_matrix, type = "lower", method = "circle", p.mat = all_pmat, show.diag = FALSE,
                             insig = "label_sig", sig.lvl = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001), pch = "*", pch.cex = 6) +
     ggplot2::theme(axis.text.y=ggplot2::element_text(size=15),
                    legend.text=ggplot2::element_text(size=15))
grDevices::pdf(file="heat_all2.pdf", height=6, width=6)
print(
  P
)
grDevices::dev.off()
```

Which produces this:

[image: test1]

As you can see, I was able to modify the `y-axis` labels with `ggplot2` theme, but not the "x-axis" labels or anything else...

So I figured I could use `ggplot_build` and tweak the plot before actually printing it, and I did the following:

```
P <- ggcorrplot2::ggcorrplot(all_matrix, type = "lower", method = "circle", p.mat = all_pmat, show.diag = FALSE,
                             insig = "label_sig", sig.lvl = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001), pch = "*", pch.cex = 6) +
     ggplot2::theme(axis.text.y=ggplot2::element_text(size=15),
                    legend.text=ggplot2::element_text(size=15))
P2 <- ggplot2::ggplot_build(P)
P2$data[[4]]$size <- 5
P2$data[[4]]$hjust <- 0
P2$data[[3]]$angle <- 15
P2$data[[3]]$colour <- "grey30"
grDevices::pdf.options(reset = TRUE, onefile = FALSE)
grDevices::pdf(file="heat_all2.pdf", height=6, width=6)
print(
  graphics::plot(ggplot2::ggplot_gtable(P2))
)
grDevices::dev.off()
```

Which produces this:

[image: test2]

Very close, but still not quite there yet. The problems I keep encountering are the following:

- The "x-axis" labels get cropped
- Weird grey area on top and bottom of the plot
- I want to change the color gradient so the darker blue and darker red
  aren't *that* dark

I attempted to solve this by adding `plot.margin=grid::unit(c(0,3,0,0),"cm")` to `theme`, but the result is this (still cropped label and more grey space on top and bottom of the plot):

[image: test3]

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the [original function](https://github.com/caijun/ggcorrplot2/blob/master/R/ggcorrplot.R#L280), the author set `expand = c(0, 0)` in `scale_x_continuous()`. You just need to modify that part to get what you want

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggcorrplot2)

data(mtcars)
# change "wt" to a very long name
names(mtcars)[6] <- "a very long name"

corrtest <- psych::corr.test(mtcars[, 1:7], adjust = "none")
all_matrix <- corrtest$r
all_pmat <- corrtest$p

###
P <- ggcorrplot2::ggcorrplot(all_matrix,
  type = "lower", method = "circle", p.mat = all_pmat, show.diag = FALSE,
  insig = "label_sig", sig.lvl = c(0.05, 0.01, 0.001), pch = "*", pch.cex = 6) +
  ggplot2::theme(axis.text.y = ggplot2::element_text(size = 15),
    legend.text = ggplot2::element_text(size = 15))

P +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.25)))
#> Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will
#> replace the existing scale.
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-09-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Let me try it out, and see also if I can change the gradient easily with `ggplot2::scale_fill_gradientn()`

Comment: Any possibility of removing the `Scale for 'x' is already present. Adding another scale for 'x', which will replace the existing scale` warning?

Comment: By the way, what's with that extra grey area added on the top and bottom of the plot? Thanks!

Comment: @DaniCee: you should create a new function based on the `ggcorplot2` then you can change the default [`col2 <- grDevices::colorRampPalette(RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(n = 11, name = "RdBu"))`](https://github.com/caijun/ggcorrplot2/blob/master/R/ggcorrplot.R#L158). Some good divergent colormap are here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37482977/what-is-a-good-palette-for-divergent-colors-in-r-or-can-viridis-and-magma-b/52812120#52812120

Comment: For the warning: you can either modify the `ggcorplot2` function directly or use `suppressWarnings()` around the `print()` call https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13286531/how-to-suppress-warnings-when-plotting-with-ggplot

Comment: I'm not sure about the extra grey area. Maybe try `ggsave()` instead? Example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51906008/786542)

Comment: the `suppressWarnings()` is what I did first, but the warning happens on the `ggcorrplot()` call, not on `print()`...